# The "+" operator is not working in my code

Tags: java, string, operators, string-concatenation

It's so weird that the `String` `+` operation has a bug:

```
String path = "/app/" + monPHost.getUsername() + "/app/" + monProcessInfo.getRegion() + "/tf/bin";

System.out.println("here it ...." + path);
```

This is the result:

```
here it ..../app/aiams/app/791
```

Where has the "/tf/bin" gone?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that you haven't made a mistake somewhere else? Is your output console scrolling horizontally and the extra output is off screen? The string concatenation in Java is well tested

Comment: @DaveL Oh my god, it' like what you said, The monProcessInfo.getRegion() return hundreds of spaces so that I can't see the "/tf/bin".

Comment: It's happened to me before, this is where Unit Testing really comes in handy so you know exactly what's being passed around

Answer (score 2):

Maybe **monProcessInfo.getRegion()** is ending with a carriage return. Try to pre-process it, strip it, and the concatenate with your string.

OR, try this:

```
String path = "/app/" + monPHost.getUsername() + "/app/" + monProcessInfo.getRegion();
path = path + "/tf/bin";
System.out.println("here it ...." + path);
```

Comment: the problem is the monProcessInfo.getRegion(), it return hundreds of spaces, hence , it can't see the string in the console output. Thank you very much.

Comment: I thank you for your kindness! Best regards. Plus one.

Answer (score 2):

As a quick work around for all the spaces you're getting:

```
String path = "/app/" + monPHost.getUsername() + "/app/" + monProcessInfo.getRegion().trim() + "/tf/bin";

System.out.println("here it ...." + path);
```

I recommend tracking this down in your process object and fixing it there, if you only ever expect an Integer result try to return one, failing fast & early can prevent a lot of downstream bugs.

Comment: This is the answer to get accepted as it came from the first solution, yet on comments. Please, @wuxue, select this one as the correct. Plus one Dave L for the nice catch.

Answer (score 1):

Given in comment you mentioned `monProcessInfo.getRegion()` is giving you a String with lots of spaces, and you haven't mentioned the type of return for this method, here is what you may do:

If it is returning a String:

It will be as easy as

```
String path = "...." + monProcessInfo.getRegion().trim() + "/tf/bin";
```

If it is returning something else:

Given String concat in Java is relying on `Object.toString()`, you can change it to:

```
String path = "...." + monProcessInfo.getRegion().toString().trim() + "/tf/bin";
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that *monProcessInfo.getRegion()* returns lots of spaces, you can try trimming it before appending it to the later part of the string.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.append("/app/" + monPHost.getUsername() + "/app/");
String region = ("" + monProcessInfo.getRegion()).trim();    
sb.append(region + "/tf/bin");

System.out.println("here it ...." + sb.toString());
```

Comment: `("" + monProcessInfo.getRegion()).trim()` ?! Do you know it create yet another `StringBuilder`?

Comment: It's already a string. You don't have to add it to an empty string.